# How do I generate an Ethereum public key from a known private key using Python

Tags: python, ethereum

I'm interested in generating an Ethereum public key from a private key using Python. I've tried googling around and found some resources but these are all JS nothing using Python itself.

Comment: try out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074253/extract-publickey-from-privatekey-input-using-python

Comment: I'm not very into these things but maybe that's your answer. https://github.com/ethereum/eth-keys#publickeyfrom_privateprivate_key---publickey

Answer (score 10):

#### Public Key vs Address

An account's address is the last 20 bytes of the keccak256 of the public key. Most tasks in Ethereum require the address instead of the public key.

#### Getting the Public Key

Install eth_keys with `pip install eth-keys`

```
from eth_keys import keys
from eth_utils import decode_hex

priv_key_bytes = decode_hex('0x44b9abf2708d9adeb1722dcc1e61bef14e5611dee710d66f106e356a111bef90')
priv_key = keys.PrivateKey(priv_key_bytes)
pub_key = priv_key.public_key

assert pub_key.to_hex() == '0xcabb8a3a73ea4a03d025a6ac2ebbbb19a545e4fb10e791ec9b5c942d77aa20760f64e4604cdfbec665435a382a8c9bfd560c6f0fca8a2708cda302f658368b36'
```

#### Getting the Address

Just in case the question was intending to ask about the address...

There are simpler ways to [generate the address from scratch](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.from_key), but since we've already done the eth-keys setup, this is a one-liner:

```
assert pub_key.to_checksum_address() == '0xa0784ba3fcea41fD65a7A47b4cc1FA4C3DaA326f'
```

Comment: Nice information. I used to think that eth address is also the public key

Comment: Thanks so much this answered my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.
I'm not exactly sure how ethereum works and what exact problem you are facing.

But a quick google gave me these links

[A reddit answer to something similar you are asking](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/69qfkv/python_script_that_converts_ethereum_private_key/)

The link which is being referred seems broken, so I did some backtracking, and here is the [probable link to the referred code](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/tools/keys.py)

[python library for ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/)